# Not decoding json inside response.body Flutter

Tags: flutter, api

I`m getting empty list for FutureBuilder, I did the same with others types of Json but this not getting me empty list, However response.body gives proper data

This is Json consisting of

```
{
  "succeeded": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "typeId": 1,
      "type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Футбол"
      },
      "startDate": "2022-07-26T12:00:00",
      "endDate": "2022-07-26T14:30:00",
      "locationId": 23,
      "location": {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "qqqq",
        "regionId": 1,
        "address": "string",
        "lockerRoom": true,
        "shower": true,
        "fieldType": 1,
        "fieldCoverage": 1,
        "latitude": 12,
        "longitude": 33,
        "link2gis": "string"
      },
      "isFree": true,
      "price": 0,
      "isPublic": true,
      "teamCount": 4,
      "teamPlayersCount": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

This is My request inside provider

```
Future<List<GameModel>> getGames() async {
        List<GameModel> result = [];
        try {
          final response = await get(
            Uri.parse(AppUrl.game),
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "content-type": "application/json"
            },
          );
          
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            GameModel item;
            List<dynamic> l = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
            print(l);
            for (var m in l) {
              item = GameModel.fromJson(m);
              result.add(item);
            }
          }
        
          return result;
        } catch (e) {
          return result;
        }
      }
```

I`m getting empty list for result
GameModel class

```
@JsonSerializable()
class GameModel {
  int? id;
  int? typeId;
  GameTypes? type;
  String? startDate;
  String? endDate;
  int? locationId;
  bool? isFree;
  int? price;
  bool? isPublic;
  int? teamCount;
  int? teamPlayersCount;
  LocationModel? location;


}
```

//removed remainings for correct posting

Comment: Can you include gameModel class too

Comment: added main part

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try catch and it will break at the error. I am sure it is breaking on GameModel.fromjson

Comment: Actually you`re right, there are two json model inside data, Ive used online converters, json_serializable, but non of them worked

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: empty data list from request, printed response.body shows correctly, but gets empty list when trying futurebuilder

Comment: If you remove the try catch where does it theow an error?